# Sum up numbers after splitting string and parsing to int

Tags: c#, parsing, split

I am learning c# and I encounter problem when attempting to sum the numbers from console input. User inserts numbers separated with commas. Then, they get splitted and at the end they should be parsed to int's for the future calculations as sum. 
Here is what I've got:

```
  int[] convertedLine;
        string stringLine = System.Console.ReadLine();
        string[] splittedLine = stringLine.Split(' ');
        var success = int.TryParse(splittedLine[0], out convertedLine);

        System.Console.WriteLine(convertedLine[0] + convertedLine[1] + convertedLine[2]);
        System.Console.ReadKey();
```

on 4th line I get error under `convertedLine`, that says 'cannot convert from  out int[] to out int'.

I will appreciate help that will put me on the right track with my problem.
Thank you.
P

---------- edit ------------

Ok, so I've got this code now and it works. Is there a nicer way to do this parsing for all splitted elements of a string?

```
 int[] convertedLine=new int[3];
        string stringLine = System.Console.ReadLine();
        string[] splittedLine = stringLine.Split(' ');
        var success1 = int.TryParse(splittedLine[0], out convertedLine[0]);
        var success2 = int.TryParse(splittedLine[1], out convertedLine[1]);
        var success3 = int.TryParse(splittedLine[2], out convertedLine[2]);
        System.Console.WriteLine(convertedLine[0] + convertedLine[1] + convertedLine[2]);
        System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the elements of the `convertedLine` array and then specify the element you want to set to the value you pass to `int.TryParse`

Your `.TryParse` should look something like this:

```
var success = int.TryParse(splittedLine[0], out convertedLine[0]);
```

**Note the [0] next to convertedLine that indicated the element in the int array you are setting**

To initialize your `convertedLine` integer array simply do this line:

```
int[] convertedLine = new int[x];
```

Where `x` is the number of elements you want to have in your array. If you don't want to limit your user to a set amount of inputs you'll have to split on your split character and then initialize your integer array to however many values you found that the user input

Comment: almost exactly, because the convertedLine array also isn't initialised

Comment: @Up All Night, thank you for your response. I realized that thing about convertedLine[]. I put 0 there and I initialized it. The code sums the elements now. I cannot think of nicer way to do this though.

Comment: @paddy Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `int[] convertedLine;` and then here: `var success = int.TryParse(splittedLine[0], out convertedLine);`

You are trying to parse to an array of integers a unique value of integers. Your code is assuming you have multiple integer as inputs

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to convert the string to int in your case you pass an array of int and the function attempt to have an int a parameter.

try this one:

```
foreach(var i in splittedLine)
{
   var success = int.TryParse(splittedLine[i], out convertedLine[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comments, I will examine the code you pasted so I understand what is happening and will respond about the result.

Comment: ok take you time the important think is to know from what the crash happen

Comment: I am not sure why with your code I get this error under splittedLine[i] and convertedLine[i]:
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Answer (score 0):

The 'out' parameter from your `int.TryParse` is a single int.  You're trying however to put that single int into an array of ints (which you've called '`convertedLine`') without specifying *where* in the array that int should go.

One option then would be to declare your int array with a fixed size (eg)

`int[5] convertedLine = new int[5];`

which then allows for up to 5 integers. Then where you have

```
var success = int.TryParse(splittedLine[0], out convertedLine);
```

you should instead set a fixed value within the array, like this:

```
int.TryParse(splittedLine[0], out convertedLine[0]);
```

As an aside you also probably want to try and parse any other ints in the same way, eg:

```
int.TryParse(splittedLine[1], out convertedLine[1]);
int.TryParse(splittedLine[2], out convertedLine[2]);
```